# Margin is rendering differently in m'soft edge Vs. Chrome/ Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have a layout (code below), which renders as intended in Chrome and Safari, but unfortunately, Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer render a black bar between the element and my nav-bar. What can I do to stop this happening?

See here -

Chrome:
[image: Chrome]

Edge:
[image: Microsoft]

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation" id="slide-nav">
  <div class="container" id="logoStripe">
     <!-- Links -->
  </div>
</div>
<div id="page-content">
  <div class="container-fluid adjustedHeight Page1B">
    <div class="video-container">
      <video autoplay loop id="video">
        <source src="Images/Medium.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.</video>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-bar{
    height:77px;
}
.adjustedHeight {
    height: calc(100vh - 77px);
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    padding: 0;
}
video {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit : cover;
}
.video-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block !important;
    position: relative;
}
.video-container video {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please create a working demo, that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @LGSon I can't really show the problem, as you need to use IE or edge, however, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qkembuth/) is a JSFiddle of the full code which creates the probem.

Comment: I'm going through some older answers of mine, and found the below. Didn't my updated answer helped you out?

Answer (score 0):

One problem here is the `Page1` rule having `margin-top: 30%;`.

When you use percent for `margin-top`, it uses the parents width to calculate the margin value, so by simply resizing the browser window, this unwanted gap increases/decreases.

***Update***

I made 2 samples, an [update of you fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/qkembuth/4/) and a very simple sample snippet showing an alternative.

Regarding the fiddle, please check if the issue is gone. What I did was simply remove the `Page1` class from its element and removed the `<div id="page-content">` element.

Sample snippet

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 80px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 80px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #bbb;
}
.content {
  height: 100%;
}
video {
  display: block;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 object-fit : contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar">

  </div>
  <div class="content">

    <video autoplay loop mob-hide id="video">
      <source src="http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
      I suggest you upgrade your browser.
    </video>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I am afraid that changing to `top: 30%;` doesn't change the problem.

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards Explain how you want it to look like and I might be able to suggest some other way to achieve what you want. Can you confirm, than when you remove the margin-top, both IE and Chrome renders the same?

Comment: I would like a full-width full height video, touching the bottom of the navbar and the bottom of the screen (no further) keep aspect ratio, overflow hidden.

Comment: If I remove the page1 css, then it renders still with a black bar in edge, but no black bar in chrome. Only difference is that the buttons shoot to the top.

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards Okay, I will be back later and draw you a sample how you could do.

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards Updated my answer